# Javascript Global Variable Value Lost

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I'm having a bit of a problem regarding global variables in that when I hit this block of code:

```
if(done === true){
    console.log(songList);
}
```

the values of done and songList are now gone, however if I output them with console.log immediately after assign done=true then they carry the expected values (songList is built up in the function run by the eval statement). Can anyone explain why this is?

```
var song = {name:"", price:"", artist:"", image:""};
var done = false;
var songList = [];

function runJSON(network,searchType){
    var URL     = returnURL(network,searchType,$('#song_field').val().split(' ').join("+"));

    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
        if(document.getElementById("box") !== "undefined"){
            clearScreen();
            createCols();
        }

        eval(network + "(data);");
        done = true; 

    });

    if(done === true){
        console.log(songList);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is explained by the fact that `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function

Comment: What you mean by *lost*, did it keep the value `false` or it becomes `undefined` ? Because the log function will show its value **before** it gets changed by the `getJSON` callback, because it is *async*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`done = true` is getting assigned in the callback from $.getJSON. So it will actually run *after* you test for `if(done === true)`.

More about $.getJSON is here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ - notice that 'success' is a callback.

If you did:

```
function runJSON(network,searchType){
    var URL     = returnURL(network,searchType,$('#song_field').val().split(' ').join("+"));

    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
        if(document.getElementById("box") !== "undefined"){
            clearScreen();
            createCols();
        }

        eval(network + "(data);");
        done = true; 

        if(done === true){
            console.log(songList);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you would see the songlist

Comment: Ahh, I see so the variable will still =true simply hasn't been run yet at this point. Thanks